# ASP.net Web API 2 controller with multiple authentication filters

Tags: .net, web-services, authentication, authorization, asp.net-web-api2

What is the intended semantics for multiple authentication filters? It is allowed? and if so, how do they work together?

Here is a specific example. Suppose I have a controller class such as

```
[BasicAuthenticator]
[LocalAuthenticator]
[Authorize]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
    {
    }

    // etc. etc
}
```

in which BasicAuthenticator and LocalAuthenticator implement IAuthenticationFilter.

Each authenticator will get a chance to succeed. If either succeeds, it will set the `context.Principal` to a new object with an appropriate ClaimsIdentity (name, type, and isAuthenticated = true).

What if an authenticator fails? I think it should do nothing, so that the other one will get a chance to succeed. Right?

And what if both succeed? Does whichever goes second erase the Principal created by the first? Wouldn't it make more sense to merge the ClaimsIdentity collections of the two Principal objects together?

If an authenticator fails, it should do nothing, Correct? Because the other authenticator might succeed. The semantics of having two authenticators is that the action will run if either one succeeds, Correct?

I think the Authorize class will look at all the ClaimsIdentity in the principal, and if any ClaimsIdentity has "isAuthenticated = true" then it will allow the controller action to run. Otherwise, it will set the status = 401. That seems to be how it works. It that correct?

The purpose of the `[AllowAnonymous]` is to disable all other authorization filters, correct? The controller (or action method) is decorated with `[AllowAnonymous]` then I assume that it should always run, even if the authentication fails. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

With the recent Authentication filter introduced in Web API 2, I guess one is supposed to introduce *one* attribute for authentication, and possibly *one* attribute for authorization, as MS team split those two concerns. So the semantic is to have *one* for authentication.

It seems to me that the fact you can add more than one authentication attribute is just a *coincidence*, because you *happen* to set filters on controllers and their actions by means of attributes, and as you can add more than one attribute... Same goes with setting authentication filter project-wide, on all actions of all controllers: because one can add more than one filter, it does not necessarily implies that one *should* add more than one authentication filter.

If you need to support more than one authentication mechanism (e.g. a `Basic` and `Local`), you could just have one single attribute/filter that intercepts the request and that will try both mechanisms, implementing whichever AND/OR custom logic you might need.

Comment: That's not true. Read this blog from MS, http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters Particularly where it says "If... the filter does not recognize the authentication scheme, do nothing and return (no-op). Another filter in the pipeline might understand the scheme." Which implies that there can be more than one authentication filter.

Comment: You are right on that. I think I did not expressed myself in the best way. Point is that one can have multiple attributes/filters, but the logic combining them cannot be customized. Instead it is somehow *imposed* from above: if the authentication passes, the identity (or what else) is set and it moves on to the next filter/attribute. If it fails, basically all following steps in the chain should be skipped. So if the following is again another authentication, it is basically useless: either will find identity already set, or it might not even be invoked.

Comment: *EDIT* I could not find before the bit where it specifically says how chaining of multiple authentication filters is supposed to work. It's in the *Implementing the AuthenticateAsync Method* section. That is the chaining logic out of the box.

Comment: This might be an unusual case for multiples: My entire site requires username/password authentication before you can access a page. A subset of those pages requires an admin password. You are not logging in as a different user, merely being challenged for additional credentials to gain temporary access to the admin pages. So _all_ controllers require the main authentication filter, admin controllers also require the additional filter to challenge for the admin password. Most often you would do this with roles/claims, but in this case multiple users are working under the main credentials.

Answer (score -3):

The last Authentication filter to run successfully simply clobbers the Principal. When you look at the Principal object and the ridiculously complex Claims collections attached to it, you will think that all this complexity is surely intended to support multiple successful authentications! But you'd be wrong. Only one can succeed. There is no reason for the complexity, other than to indulge the vanity of some architect at Microsoft.

Comment: The paradigm for authentication is more like "one identity per authentication method." The ClaimsPrincipal can be used to query its multiple underlying ClaimsIdentity instances. Have you tried having each of your filters simply add a new identity to the existing principal, rather than constructing a new principal?